# Marp multiple images on slide

Tags: markdown, presentation, marp, marpit

How can you insert multiple images on a slide in Marp / Markdown at different locations?
I got some success using something like this, but it works only for 1 image:

```
<!-- _footer: "![](/Users/dan.stancu/Pictures/markdown/markdown.png)" -->

<style>
footer {
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 280px;
}
footer img {
    height: 400px;
    float: right;
 }
</style>
```

Tried using footer code but only works for 1 image

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find a solution:

```
<style>
img[alt~="top-right"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}
</style>

<style>
img[alt~="bottom-right"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  right: 0px;
}
</style>


![top-right](image.png)
![bottom-right](image.png)
```